# how to add Javascript code in specific page in SquareSpace website

Tags: javascript, code-injection, squarespace

I tried to add the custom javascript code in code injection,

It worked and I can see the code on all pages.

But I need this form only homepage

This is my code

```
<div class="_form_8"></div><script src="https://adriamarble.*****com/f/embed.php?id=***" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the global header or footer injection points, use [the per-page header code injection](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908-Using-Code-Injection#toc-per-page-code-injection) for just that specific page.

> *You can also inject code into a specific page:*
>
> *1) Hover over the page in the Pages panel.
>
>     2) Click the icon.
>
>     3) Click Advanced.*
>
> *Page Header Code Injection adds code to the  tag of that page.*

If you need to add code to the body of a specific page, add a [Code Block](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206543167-Code-Blocks) or [Markdown Block](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205813788-Markdown-Blocks) and then insert your code there.

Comment: I need to add script to body
No header and footer

Comment: You said *"I tried to add the custom javascript code in code injection, It worked and I can see the code on all pages."*. It sounds like it worked when you added it to header/footer code injection. So where did you add it? In Squarespace the term "code injection" always refers to header and footer. If you added it somewhere else, please clarify. Also, I added to my answer to include using code blocks or markdown blocks.

Comment: Thanks so much this is helpful for me